# How do I change the FontSize and style of the data header in my xaml Datagrid

Tags: xaml, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, fonts

I have a datagrid which auto generates the columns.

```
<DataGrid Name="QueryGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="1000" Width="1135" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryTable}" Visibility="{Binding Path=QueryGridVisiblity, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"  />
```

I have to make the column names bold. How do i do this? Any suggestions?

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the answer i have found:

```
 <DataGrid Name="QueryGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="900" Width="1135" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryTable}" Visibility="{Binding Path=QueryGridVisiblity, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style 
                        TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter 
                            Property="Background" 
                            Value="SteelBlue"
                            />
                        <Setter 
                            Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                            Value="Center"
                            />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```